# forcasting anomaly in products

Tags: dataframe, time-series, prediction, anomaly-detection, semisupervised-learning

I have a question about the forecasting of anomalies. I would be very grateful if you could refer me to some papers that deal with this kind of problem or give me some hints to start with this problem.

I have some products that go to a bigger machine and some forces act on these products for about 5 minutes. After that, some of these products are not normal and they are anomalies.
I want to predict an anomaly before it occurs.

The data is as follows: I have more than 100000 products and for each product, I have 120 features that are measured 1000 times (during 5 minutes).
Hello Mr.
I have a question about the forecasting of anomalies. I would be very grateful if you could refer me to some papers that deal with this kind of problem or give me some hints to start with this problem.

I have some products that go to a bigger machine and some forces act on these products for about 5 minutes. After that, some of these products are not normal and they are anomalies.
I want to predict an anomaly before it occurs.

The data is as follows: I have more than 100000 products and for each product, I have 120 features that are measured 1000 times (during 5 minutes).

point: Most of the papers I have seen were about predicting anomalies in the machine. For example, there are some sensors in a large machine that are monitored till they show strange behavior. This means that the machine is close to breaking and something needs to be changed to make it works normally again. All these examples are about machines and not related to the products

[image]

Comment: How does your data about the final samples look like? Do you have ground-thruth label of whether a given sample was a deviation or not?

Comment: Btw, this is not a probgramming question, and would be more on topic for http://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have some parts of the data which are labeled as Ok or anomaly.

Comment: What is the nature of your? Are there distinct "events" at particular points in time that cause them, or something that happens gradually?